# read numbers from image

Tags: python, python-tesseract

So here is the image I want to get output from:

[image]

I have tried using pytesseract like this (mask2 is the image):

```
number = pytesseract.image_to_string("mask2.png", config='--psm 7')
print(number)
```

I have used every possible config but I just get weird outputs like "ihioee" for example. Is there any better way to read text from an image than that? If I just remove the psm config I get no output...

Answer (score 0):

The following adjustments can improve the readability of the image and OCR accuracy:

1. boost DPI, 300 DPI or above
2. set text size to 12 points (minimum)
3. set a good image brightness
4. Convert the image to Gray scale
5. Remove the noise pixels